# Bash scripting regular expressions

Tags: regex, bash, unix

I'm trying to match a version number from a string in the format 4.6, or 2.8.  I have the following which I will eventually use in a function in my .bashrc file to find the OS version:

```
function test () {
    string="abc ABC12 123 3.4 def";
    echo `expr match "$string" '[0-9][.][0-9]'`
}
```

However, this doesn't match the 3.4 in the string.  Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Thanks.

Comment: can't see why it souldn't work - maybe, try using the "." as it is escaped instead of in bracets eg. `[0-9]\.[0-9]`

Comment: Isn't `[.]` any single character? Does your function match anything at all? I don't know the specifics of regex in bash, but I would assume the match would be something like "2 1".

Comment: @oliver: not if within brakets, then it's used as-is

Comment: Are you sure you understand what should happen? Seems to me that `expr match STRING REGEX` returns 0 if there's a match, nonzero otherwise. This is what happens with your example on my machine.

Comment: I got it working using    expr match "$string" '.*([0-9][.][0-9]*)'    This way it successfully prints the x.x number.

Comment: again, I don't know why the original regex doesn't work because it should, and does, match exactly 3.4 - why it doesn't give you match as a result I don't know

Comment: the `.*([0-9][.][0-9]*)` does match more than what you want. the second "*" as a modifier will match between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible (greedy) which means that if you have more than one occurance of a "x.y" number it will match them all eg. `string="abc AB123 123 3.4 4.5 6.7 def"` will match `3.4 4.5 6.7`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, you can drop the `echo` - `expr` prints its result to stdout in any case.

Second, your regex needs brackets (otherwise it prints the number of characters matched, not the match itself), and it needs to begin with `.*`.

```
expr match "$string" '.*\([0-9][.][0-9]\)'
```

From the `info expr` page:

> STRING : REGEX'
>
> ```
>  Perform pattern matching.  The arguments are converted to strings
>  and the second is considered to be a (basic, a la GNU `grep')
>  regular expression, with a `^' implicitly prepended.  The first
>  argument is then matched against this regular expression.
>
>  If the match succeeds and REGEX uses `\(' and `\)', the `:'
>  expression returns the part of STRING that matched the
>  subexpression; otherwise, it returns the number of characters
>  matched.
> ```

Answer (score 7):

Depending on your version of bash, there's no need to call out to expr:

```
$ [[ "abc ABC12 123 3.4 def" =~ [0-9][.][0-9] ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
3.4
```

Answer (score 4):

Thinking outside the box: if what you are looking for is determining the OS version in a script, just use `uname -r` or `uname -v` (it's POSIX). Messing with regular expression is likely to have issues as each OS may have different ways to express its version. OS vendors are so creative in inventing version jumps forward and backward, some have letters in there, and even roman numerals are not unheard of (think *System V*).

See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uname.html

I use in my .profile a snippet like this:

```
case "`uname -sr`" in
  (*BSD*)     OS=`uname -s`;;
  (SunOS\ 4*) OS=SunOS;;
  (SunOS\ 5*) OS=Solaris;;
  (IRIX\ 5*)  OS=IRIX;;
  (HP*)       OS=HP-UX;;
  (Linux*)    OS=Linux;;
  (CYGWIN*)   OS=Cygwin;;
  (*)         OS=generic
esac
```

Answer (score 3):

On Mac OS X 10.6.8:

```
# cf. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22429
string="abc ABC12 123 3.4 def"
expr "$string" : '.*\([0-9].[0-9]\)'    #  3.4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
expr match "$string" '.*[0-9][.][0-9]'
```

Comment: don't know about the bash part but just the regex will match everything until (and including) 3.4

Comment: Without brackets this just prints the number of characters, too