# Convert [[ ]] command to test expression format

Tags: linux, bash

Say you have the user enter in a number 0-3 and want to test it. The most common way seems to be:

```
[[ $var =~ ^[0-3]$ ]]
```

But how would you use this with:

```
test expression
```

My initial attempt doesn't evaluate correctly, e.g.

```
read -p "Enter selection [0-3] > "
if test $REPLY == '^[0-3]$' ; then
...
```

It just evaluates the `if` statement as false.

Comment: `test` command does not support regular expressions. use `expr` instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159441/bash-scripting-regular-expressions

Comment: `test "$var" = 0 || test "$var" = 1 || test "$var" = 2 || test "$var" = 3 && echo okay`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test` is equivalent to the `[ ]` structure, but not to `[[ ]]`, which is an extended version. The regex `=~` is only available in the extended test, so for simple `test` or `[ ]` you have to pull the regex evaluation from elsewhere.

One fix is `grep`. This pipeline will catch and print the matches:

```
echo "$REPLY" | grep '^[0-3]$'
```

Using `test` with a string evaluates positively if the string is non-empty. Compare these two:

```
test "" && echo ok
```

and

```
test "a" && echo ok
```

Knowing this, it's now easy to build a compound test from the both elements.

```
test "$(echo "$REPLY" | grep '^[0-3]$')"
```

And this can be applied to the script:

```
read -p "Enter selection [0-3] > "
if test "$(echo "$REPLY" | grep '^[0-3]$')"; then
    ...
fi
```

Comment: Cool! This is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex in Bash like this:

```
echo -n "Your answer> "
read REPLY
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    echo Numeric
else
    echo Non-numeric
fi
```

Please check the post *[Using Bash's regular expressions](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2693361/unix-tip-using-bash-s-regular-expressions.html)*.